# Can suggested tag synonyms be added to the "Review" queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It would be great if the suggested tag synonyms page:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

Where displayed in the standard "Review" queue:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/review

This would encourage users with enough rep to actually up or down vote tag synonyms.